# Prove the set equation

Tags: general-topology

How to prove that if $A\backslash B=A$ and $B\subset A$ then $B=\varnothing$.

Can we prove that using some sets relations?

Answer (score 3):

If B has an element say $x$, then since $B\subset A$, $x$ must be in $A$ also. Thus, $x$ is contained in both $A$ and $B$ so that $x\notin A\setminus B$. This contradicts the fact that $A\setminus B=A$. So there can not be an element in $B$. That is, $B=\emptyset$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $B$ is not the null set, then there exists at least one point $b\in B$. Also remember that the whole set is given by $A\cup A^c$. Now try and apply the two relations you have.

Answer (score 0):

If $B \neq \varnothing$ then $A \neq \varnothing$, and $(A\setminus B)\subset A\Rightarrow A = (A\setminus B)\cup B\subset A\cup B=A\Rightarrow A\setminus A \neq \varnothing$, contradiction. So $B = \varnothing$.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my approach:

$$C\backslash B = A \implies \forall x \in B, x\notin A$$
$$B \subset A \implies \forall x \in B, x\in A$$

I changed A to C in the first condition for purpose of generality. It still holds.